# How to add text in New File Name in Visual Studio Code using command ids?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I've been learning more recently about user snippets and due to some things I've been reading on here I got interested about combining them as well using the multi-command extension.

I'm writing my first sequence and this is where I am at now:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
{
  "command": "multiCommand.createFolderStructure",
  "sequence": [
    {
      "command": "renameFile",
      "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !explorerResourceIsRoot && !explorerResourceReadonly && !inputFocus"
    },
    {
      "command": "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !explorerResourceIsRoot && !inputFocus"
    },
    {
      "command": "explorer.newFile"
    },
    { "command": "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction" },
    {
      "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
      "args": {
        "snippet": ".js"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

]

So what this does at the moment is:

1. Opens the renaming for current active folder.
2. Copies the name of the folder.
3. Creates new file in active folder.
4. Pastes the name of the folder from clipboard.

With the last command I was trying to add `.js` at the end of it. But it does not seems to be working. The insert snippet only works in the editor. I didn't find anything else that would work for me. Is there anyone that knows whats a good command id for this particular thing?

Comment: does the `type` command work https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_command-arguments

Comment: @rioV8 no, I have tried it

Comment: Are there are any existing files in the folder?  I am wondering if it is am acceptable workflow to open an editor for the folder you want to add the file into?  It is pretty easy then but you may have empty folders.

Comment: @Mark I am not sure I understand the question. What I was trying to do is create a sequence of commands that after I create a folder for example named Component for a react component and pressing a keyboard shortcut will create inside the folder 3 files with the names Component.js, index.js and Component.styled.js which also will have somme snippets inserted inside...however when creating a  file under current folder I could only copy paste content into the title to give it a name, not add a custom text after what I paste. I will edit my answer if you are interested in what I ended up  doing.

Comment: That answers it - the folder would be empty so the easy method I was thinking about will not work.

Comment: @Mark I also wanted to thank you for all your regex responses on this website and sharing your knowdlege..is because of answers like yours I started to learn more regex and actually apply it.

Comment: Thank you.  I really appreciate it (I also wish the TM_SELECTED_TEXT thing was working for you).  It should...

Comment: @Mark, yeah not sure why...but at this point I have that snippet working on a keyboard shortcut which is also good, maybe its going to work in the future who knows but I am happy with the keyboard shortcut one just as much.

Comment: @Mark  just realised something....If I only press the s and then hit tab on the snippet sdiv that appears...it is working!!! but if I write the whole 'sdiv' prefix its not working...that must be some kind of bug right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have managed to do what I needed but in an overly complicated way. If anybody knows the answer to my questions I would still like it. This is what I did:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.createFolderStructure",
      "interval": 30,
      "sequence": [
        "renameFile",
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        "explorer.newFile",
        "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
        "workbench.action.quickOpen",
        "workbench.files.action.focusOpenEditorsView",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "$CLIPBOARD.js"
          }
        },
        "editor.action.selectAll",
        "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
        "workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer",
        "renameFile",
        "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

This is the complete series of actions I had to do for all the requirements I had if anybody is interested. However this will not work for you as it is as you also need the user snippets I defined

```
{
      "command": "multiCommand.createFolderStructure",
      "interval": 100,
      "sequence": [
        "renameFile",
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        "explorer.newFile",
        "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
        "workbench.action.quickOpen",
        "workbench.files.action.focusOpenEditorsView",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "$CLIPBOARD.js"
          }
        },
        "editor.action.selectAll",
        "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
        "workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer",
        "renameFile",
        "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
        "workbench.action.quickOpen",
        "workbench.files.action.focusOpenEditorsView",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:capitalize}/}.styled.js"
          }
        },
        "editor.action.selectAll",
        "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "name": "Simple Component"
          },
          "when": "editorLangId == javascript"
        },

        "workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer",
        "explorer.newFile",
        "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
        "workbench.action.quickOpen",
        "workbench.files.action.focusOpenEditorsView",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "index.js"
          },
          "when": "editorLangId == javascript"
        },
        "editor.action.selectAll",
        "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "name": "Styled Template"
          },
          "when": "editorLangId == javascript"
        },
        "workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer",
        "explorer.newFile",
        "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
        "workbench.action.quickOpen",
        "workbench.files.action.focusOpenEditorsView",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "name": "Export Default From"
          },
          "when": "editorLangId == javascript"
        },
        "workbench.action.files.saveAll",
        "workbench.action.closeAllEditors"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: I have a file open in the workspace and the `"$CLIPBOARD.js"` ends up in the other file, not the new file, the new file stays empty

Comment: weird it might be because of the computer being slower or something and it does not have time to listen to the commands...works perfectly for me. Try to put a bigger interval like "interval": 100, and see if that helps

Comment: as you can see in this video I created a whole serios of actions that starts with this sequence and it works perfectly for me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KzMvHO2Rp4

Comment: yes increasing the interval results in the text in the new file